# How to count number of students which have passed or failed in multiple subjects in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have a excel sheet like :

Sr.no___RollNumber__Subject1__Subject2__Subject3

1.-------------001-------------Pass----------Pass------Pass

2.-------------002-------------NULL----------Pass------Pass

3.-------------003-------------Pass----------Fail------NULL

4.-------------004-------------Fail----------Pass------NULL

*NULL Means Blank Cells

I want to write a single excel formula to get the count of all the students who have passed in at least 2 of the 3 subjects.

Comment: add an extra column that counts the Passes per row, then sum the new column if the value is greater than 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((C2:C5="Pass")+(D2:D5="Pass")+(E2:E5="Pass")>=2)*1)
```

[image]

Comment: just use the COUNTIF() function instead. 
"     =COUNTIF(C2:E2,"Pass")  "
Then sum the new column if the count is > 1
"   =COUNTIF(G2:G5,">1")  "

Comment: @JoeBourne OP wrote `I want to write a single excel formula` so I went the SUMPRODUCT way.  Otherwise I would have suggested the helper column.

Comment: Thanx a lot..!! exactly what i needed.. :)